# autocomplete-python unable to find python binary

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

I am working with python and django in Atom, however I get this error when I want to run the server.

[image]

I change the path several times but nothing changed.

Comment: Please add the error message to the question instead of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try searching for the error message?

By default when you install Python on Windows, it is not accessible globally. In order to be able to access it from anywhere, you need to add your python installation folder to your `PATH` variables

1. From the desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
2. In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab.
3. In the Advanced section, click the Environment Variables button.
4. Highlight the Path variable in the Systems Variable section and click the Edit button.
5. Add the path of your python executable(c:\Python27). Each different directory is separated with a semicolon. (Note: do not put spaces between elements in the PATH. Your addition to the PATH should read ;c:\Python27 NOT ; C\Python27)
6. Apply the changes. You might need to restart your system, though simply restarting cmd.exe should be sufficient.
7. Launch cmd and try again. It should work.

Also since you're using Atom, you might be able to skip this and set the path to the Python executable in Atom's settings.
I have never used Atom, but most IDE's allow you to do so in the settings.

Comment: Thank you Resley. I already did this and set the path to this address: C:\Users\raheleh\Miniconda3\Scripts , but nothing change.

Comment: Try `C:\Users\raheleh\Miniconda3\` without the Scripts